# How to read a text file from SD card in Android device through command prompt?

Tags: android, adb, command-prompt, android-permissions

There is a folder called "D_Permision" SD Card and there is a text file called "permission.txt" in it.

I want to read this text file through command prompt and display its content in the command prompt(Not in a separate file)

When I use

```
adb pull permission.txt /sdcard/D_Permission
```

it gives following error

> remote object 'permission.txt' does not exist.

but I used

```
adb push permission.txt /sdcard/D_Permission
```

(successfully added permission.txt to D_Permission folder)

and the tried to pull.but I get same error.

> sdcard/D_permission has both read / write permission

So how to read this text file through command prompt and display its content in the cmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pull the file.
`adb` provides shell acces, so you can do a `cat`:

```
adb shell cat /sdcard/D_Permission/foo.txt
```

If the file does not exist though, you'll still get "does not exists" error of course, which is normal.

Answer (score 0):

I directly use the path "`/mnt/external_sd/`.. Path of File.".

But it was only work with my Device

Maybe you forget these permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```